# Grouping table header created using divs

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have created a table using div's Now I want multiple columns to share a single header which should be at the center of the column.

which would typically look like below :

`---Header---
a | b | C | d
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
p | q | R | S`

HTML:

```css
.div-table {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  /* cellspacing:poor IE support for  this */
}

.div-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.div-table-col {
  float: left;
  /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <div class="div-table">
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Header</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Header</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Header</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">001</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">002</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">003</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">004</div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">xxx</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">www</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">www1</div>

      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">ttt</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">uuu</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Mkkk</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Mkkkww</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

```
CSS:
.div-table {
  display: table;         
  width: auto;         
  background-color: #eee;         
  border: 1px solid #666666;         
  border-spacing: 5px; /* cellspacing:poor IE support for  this */
}
.div-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.div-table-col {
  float: left; /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;         
  width: 200px;         
  background-color: #ccc;  
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/st8qyat9/6/ which has table implementation using divs.
In this example instead of having the header at top of each row, I need to group header which would look like the above description.

Comment: Why do you want format a table with div's? Content looks like table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I can think of for this is to create a new class for your header (for this example I've listed it as colspan as this is what you'd normally use with actual table cells to create what you're looking for).

Effectively you want a span that is four times (or as many times as you need) the size of the .div-table-col class - so therefore you can list width as 100% to ensure you can use the header class on any table you wish!

Additionally, you can include text-align:center; to this so you don't have to include it within the html itself.

Hope that helps!

```css
.div-table {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  /* cellspacing:poor IE support for  this */
}

.div-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.div-table-col {
  float: left;
  /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.div-table-colspan {
  float: left;
  /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <div class="div-table">
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-colspan">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">001</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">002</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">003</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">004</div>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">xxx</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">www</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">www1</div>

      </div>
      <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col">ttt</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">uuu</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Mkkk</div>
        <div class="div-table-col">Mkkkww</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for answering :) 
 Answer works well for the question which I have posted, But It would not work if the table has multiple headers and each header corresponds to different, number of columns.

Comment: That's very true - in instances like those, what would be viable would be to insert multiple divs with the 'div-table-colspan' class, then to do this (so say for instance, you require a table where there are five columns, one header occupies 3 columns and another occupies the other two):

<div class="div-table-colspan" style="width:60%;">Header1</div>
<div class="div-table-colspan" style="width:40%;">Header 2</div>

Comment: Thanks, @DKyleo, I will use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="div-table">
            <div>
                <div align="center">Header</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col">001</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">002</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">003</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">004</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col">xxx</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">yyy</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">www</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">www1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col">ttt</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">uuu</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Mkkk</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Mkkkww</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```